# Count number of occurrences of value in JSON fields with pattern stored in JSON Column (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a JSON column, `telework`, stored in Postgres which looks like

```
"{ ..., 
  "biweeklyWeek1-locationMon": "alternative", 
  "biweeklyWeek1-locationTues": "agency", 
  "biweeklyWeek1-locationWeds": "alternative", 
  "biweeklyWeek1-locationThurs": "alternative", 
  "biweeklyWeek1-locationFri": "alternative", 
  ... ,
  "biweeklyWeek2-locationMon": "alternative", 
  "biweeklyWeek2-locationTues": "agency", 
  "biweeklyWeek2-locationWeds": "alternative", 
  "biweeklyWeek2-locationThurs": "alternative", 
  "biweeklyWeek2-locationFri": "alternative", 
... }"
```

I need to **count the number of occurrences of "alternative"** in the `biweeklyWeek1-location*` fields and `biWeeklyWeek2-location*` fields separately and select these two as separate fields in the main query. It's possible that the values in these fields could be filled, blank (`""`), or `null`. Also, it's possible that these fields are partially or completely missing in the JSON.

```
select a.id, 
       a.name,
       a.telework->>??? as alternativePerWeek1, 
       a.telework->>??? as alternativePerWeek2,
       ...
```

Strangely enough, even when I do the following single example with `->` a hard-coded ID, I get a NULL result even though I see that it shouldn't be NULL:

`select telework, telework->'biweeklyWeek1-locationMon' from ets.agreement_t where id = 24763;`

[image]

Comment: Sorry it's output in PgAdmin like that. Let me change it for clarity - Done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scalar sub-query after unnesting the JSON using `json_each()`

```
select ... other columns ...,
       (select count(*)
        from json_each_text(s.telework) as x(key,value)
        where x.key like 'biweeklyWeek1-location%'
          and x.value = 'alternative') as week1_alternative_count,
       (select count(*)
        from json_each_text(s.telework) as x(key,value)
        where x.key like 'biweeklyWeek2-location%'
          and x.value = 'alternative') as week2_alternative_count
from some_schedule s
```

Btw: the recommended data type to store JSON is `jsonb`

Comment: Excellent thanks. But in my case, the JSON contained backslashes and initial/terminal ". Thus, before applying `json_each_text`, I had to do this: `rtrim(ltrim(regexp_replace(CAST(telework AS VARCHAR), '\\','','g'),'\"'),'\"')::json`

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: telework JSON column contains a list of (key, value) pair and key is in the format `biweekly?-location???`.

1. use json_each() and lateral join to split the JSON column into (key, value) pair for each row.
2. extract the prefix and aggregate as below:

```
 select s.id,
        s.name,
        substring(t.key,1,22)  as week_location,
        sum(case when t.value::text = '"alternative"' then 1 else 0 end) as  alternative_count
   from some_schedule s,
   lateral json_each(s.telework) t
   group by 1,2,3;
```

The output is like:

```
id |name |week_location         |alternative_count|
---+-----+----------------------+-----------------+
101|david|biweeklyWeek1-location|                4|
101|david|biweeklyWeek2-location|                4|
```

EDIT: Per comment, json_each() can also be used in SELECT

```
select id,
       name,
       telework,
       json_each(telework) as key_value
  from some_schedule;
```

Output:

```
id |name |key_value                                    |
---+-----+---------------------------------------------+
101|david|(biweeklyWeek1-locationMon,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek1-locationTue,"""agency""")     |
101|david|(biweeklyWeek1-locationWed,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek1-locationThu,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek1-locationFri,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek2-locationMon,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek2-locationTue,"""agency""")     |
101|david|(biweeklyWeek2-locationWed,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek2-locationThu,"""alternative""")|
101|david|(biweeklyWeek2-locationFri,"""alternative""")|
```

You can also parse the `key_value` column to get what you need

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand this `lateral` stuff. Is there a more straightforward way to use `json_each`, like in a Join or an independent inner Select or something.

Comment: @geneb.  json_each() returns one or more (key, value) pair of `telework` JSON column for each row in `some_scheule`. Lateral is a join by appending the result to each row, which is similar to correlated subquery that used in SELECT or WHERE clause but it's used in FROM clause.

Comment: Thanks, when I do `select ... , json_each(telework) from ets.agreement_t;` it says `Cannot deconstruct a scalar`.

Comment: The column is defined as `json` rather than `jsonb`. Maybe I need to do `jsonb_each`.

Comment: I found the problem I had to remove special chars (backslashes/initial & terminal quote) before applying JSON functions, as follows: `rtrim(ltrim(regexp_replace(CAST(telework AS VARCHAR), '\\','','g'),'\"'),'\"')::json`.